# How to add .gif support to the android push?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, push, android-glide

I am trying to add .gif support to the FCM push notification. I am receiving push with proper url. But I am unable to find out a way to show .gif images in Big Image.

Is there any work around to show .gif in the push of android?
Is it Glide library support for this?